# How to merge two array in mysql query

Tags: php

From MySQL join query I got result like:

```
Array ( [0] => c1 [1] => ot1 [2] => ot1 [3] => R )
Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 10 [2] => 15 [3] => 5 )
```

But I want result like:

```
c1 = [20]
ot1 = [10,15]
R = [5]
```

Please help me.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: `ot1 = [10,15]` in which case it take 10,15

Comment: if array key same like "ot1"

Comment: Enlighten us about what you tried thus-far, aside your main code you provided, to solve it yourself by editing it into your question and not in comments!... its called "showing effort" and is a good medicine against down-voters. End of "Triage Review" --> Requires "effort" and "editing".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
$array1 = array( 0 => 'c1', 1 => 'ot1', 2 => 'ot1' 3 => 'R' )
$array2 = array( 0 => 20, 1 => 10, 2 => 15, 3 => 5 )
```

Try this:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++){

        if(!isset(${$array1[$i]}))
            ${$array1[$i]} = [];
        ${$array1[$i]}[] = $array2[$i];

    }
```

Note that this works only when keys are continous integers starting from 0 and both arrays have the same dimension

Comment: foreach would remove the keys restriction

Comment: agreed, it's just an old habit of mine, doing iterations like this when the keys are integers

Comment: not to be rude, but you may consider improving the code using PHP best practices - you've got no psr2, inline conditionals and variable variables, all of it is considered a bad practice

Comment: i guess it depends on how you are used to read/write code. To me, this version seems as readable as yours

Comment: Don't take is as an attack, it's juast a piece of advice. I did not make up the good practices, we should all try to make code follow guidelines accepted by most programmers so it would NOT depend on how you are used to read/write code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first array is called `$array1` and the other is called `$array2` try this:

```
$merged = []; //new array for merged values
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) { //iterate over the array which holds keys
    if (!isset($merged[$value])) { //if a key does not exist in new array yet
        $merged[$value] = []; //add it
    }
    $merged[$value][] = $array2[$key]; //add new value from the other array under this key
}
```

as long as the integrity of your arrays is preserved, there are no restrictions about continuous keys like in the other answer

Comment: happy to help. Please mark my answer as the correct one.

Comment: Array ( [0] => 20 ) Array ( [0] => 10 ) Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 15 ) Array ( [0] => 5 );

Comment: Result must be:Array ( [0] => 20 )  Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 15 ) Array ( [0] => 5 )

Comment: Sound like a totally different queation but what the hell: `$arrayIndexed = array_values($merged);`. <- add below the foreach loop. But please try not to change questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this one

```
$array1 = array('c1', 'ot1', 'ot1', 'R');
$array2 = array(20, 10, 15, 5);
$array3 = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    if (array_key_exists($array1[$i], $array3)) {
        $array3[$array1[$i]] = array($array3[$array1[$i]], $array2[$i]);
    } else {
        $array3[$array1[$i]] = $array2[$i];
    }
}
```